# Enable website hosting in AWS while creating a bucket using SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using AWS SDK, and I am able to create buckets and manipulate keys. At the time of creation of bucket I also want to enable it for website hosting.

This is what I am using for creation

```
    $result = $s3->createBucket([
        'Bucket' => $buck_name
    ]);
```

From what I found, This is how we add website configuration

```
$result = $s3->putBucketWebsite(array(
    'Bucket'        => $buck_name,    
    'IndexDocument' => array('Suffix' => 'index.html'),
    'ErrorDocument' => array('Key' => 'error.html'),
));
```

But this is not enabling website hosting,I also have uploaded both files(index and error) just in case. But I am getting this error

```
InvalidArgumentException: Found 1 error while validating the input provided for the PutBucketWebsite operation: [WebsiteConfiguration] is missing and is a required parameter in
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$bucket = $buck_name;

// 1. Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory();

// 2. Add website configuration.
$result = $s3->putBucketWebsite(array(
    'Bucket'        => $bucket,    
    'IndexDocument' => array('Suffix' => 'index.html'),
    'ErrorDocument' => array('Key' => 'error.html'),
));

// 3. Retrieve website configuration.
$result = $s3->getBucketWebsite(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
));
echo $result->getPath('IndexDocument/Suffix');
```